# High poly mesh won't bake onto low poly mesh, but appears on normal map. file included

Tags: baking

i'm a beginner so the issue might be really simple, here is the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h95kw2zfemhsi0x/uno1.blend?dl=0)

i'm trying to bake my high poly mesh onto my lower poly mesh and i'm running into issues and i don't understand why, i did everything as shown in videos. i'd love some help on solving this

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please describe the issue? I don't see any problem, except maybe that your low-poly is not very low-poly

Comment: the high poly mesh didn't even go on to the low poly mesh, the low poly looks the exact same. also, this is my first time trying to bake ever

Comment: your low-poly looks pretty close to your high-poly, so when you bake you won't have a lot of bumps to bake, maybe try with a lower topology, but make sure that this low-poly has a correct topology (i.e. you need to retopology)